# How do you write and read an abstract class pointer to a file in c++?

Tags: c++, file, abstract-class

I have several classes that all inherit the same interface. These classes are instantiated and saved in interface pointers. For example:

```
struct Class {
private:
    Function* function;
};
```

I need to save the function to a file, and am wondering if saving the function as (*function), I will need to add an enum or do instance checking? The function objects contain one method that needs to be called from the abstract function class after loading the file and I want to make sure I am able to call that function after loading the file.

Comment: You normally don't write pointers to a file at all. They are only good during the lifetime of the program. Once it is terminated, all bets are off.

Comment: Think of it this way, your OS has a virtual memory manager and uses address randomization. You run your code once, get some memory address for your object and write that address to disk. You run your code again, now with a completely different address space, and read the old address back from the file. What do you think happens when you reference the old memory location?

Comment: I know, that it why I wrote I am saving the function as (*function) which as I recall means the function object.I would then load it into a new pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can do: Make a list of all the function pointers that you would want to store, assign an unchangeable unique number to each, write that number to the file, and upon reading, replace it with the function pointer.

Comment: I was planning on writing the fields to a file. For example: function->points[] are written, and then need to be loaded, and then the function re-instantiated with the appropriate subclass constructor with the points as arguments. Then that object will be referenced by the pointer. I want to be able to call the subclass methods upon loading though. I am not sure if I will be able to do that. Will I be able to call the functions in the sub-classes upon loading? Will a simple instance check do, or will I need to add an enum? I am thinking that the class will lose it's instance type when saved.

Comment: I now realized, I am thinking of Java serialization and that I probably will need to use an enum. Is that really the best way to go about it?

Comment: You may want to review the Factory Design pattern.  Use ID values or text to determine what kind of child should be created when reading the file.

Comment: Wouldn't an enum id work better? The factory would write the enum to file and use it when reading the file to instantiate the right object.